# UIImagePickerView Custom UI for photo library

Tags: ios, ios6, customization, photolibrary

Is there a simpler, "more modern" way of coding a `UIImagePickerView` PhotoLibrary Custom UI in iOS 6? Or do we still need to do the whole `scrollview with UIImageViews`? Any help is greatly appreciated!